# Pokemon GO with Hotspot

Tags: pokemon-go

My smartphone isn't powerful enough to play Pokemon GO, or doesn't have GPS. However, my tablet does.

If I were to activate the WiFi Hotspot feature on my phone, would I be able to play the game on my tablet?

Comment: You're saying that your tablet already has WiFi. Why would you want to grant it the same access from your phone?

Comment: Why not use your phone?

Comment: yep, but i dont have wi-fi everywhere, soo i activate my data mobile nd share whit  tablet, but dont know if it would work

Comment: @Patonovent Can your tablet access cellular data? Not all  makes/models are eligible.

Comment: No sean, my tablet dont has 3g or 4g

Comment: @Patonovent Then I don't believe it would be possible. Even if you tried to tether your phone with your tablet.

Comment: The GPS location is just as important as the data connection. Does your tablet have GPS functionality? If not, you wouldn't be able to play even if you did get a data connection.

Comment: If you can make an hotspot off your phone you should be able to connect your tablet with that signal.

Comment: Yeah my tablet has GPS Mage Xy, and if thats works Damek then i will be fine :)

Answer (score 1):

Pokemon Go needs a GPS-derived position to work, and internet access.  The type of internet connection (cell or wifi) should not matter.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your tablet probably doesn't have GPS which is required to play the game.

So unless your tablet has GPS (unlikely as it has no 3G or 4G) then you will not be able to play.

Answer (score -1):

You can log in and everything, but when I tired to use my mobile hotspot for my sons tablet so we could walk together it did not work well for him.

It showed the gyms but no PokeStops no Pokemon ever popped up and his character just ran back and forth between blocks as the loading icon constantly showed. My guess is that it knew the general area he was in because of the tower reference from my cell signal, but it could not use gps for a precise location.

Just try it... Maybe you will have better luck.